# Why would ".contains" return false for objects pulled directly from a collection?

Tags: java, collections, ormlite

```
private Collection<Episode> episodes = new ArrayList<Episode>();

public void checkEpisodes(String string) {
    for(Episode episode : this.episodes){
        System.out.println(string + this.episodes.contains(episode));
    }
}
```

Why would the above code print false?

I'm using a collection because that's what ormlite allows. I think the issue may be caused by ormlite anyways, because a very similar class has an identical method that prints true.

What I'm trying to do is modify an object returned by:

```
public Episode findEpisode(int num) {
    checkEpisodes("Find: ");
    for(Episode episode : this.episodes) {
        if(episode.getNumber()==num) {
            return episode;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But modification of that object isn't saved.  I'm assuming because it's not contained within the Collection.

My solution, which works but isn't ideal:

```
public void modifyEpisode(Episode episode) {
    checkEpisodes("Modify: ");
    for (Iterator<?> it = this.episodes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        if (((Episode) it.next()).getNumber()==episode.getNumber()) {
            it.remove();
            addEpisode(episode.getNumber(), episode.getLink(), episode.getLinkLabel());
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to see more of my code, just ask, the project is somewhat involved, but it's hosted on sourceforge and I can post a link to it if necessary.

Comment: Do you have a `compareTo` method in `Episode`?

Comment: @josh.trow `ArrayList#contains` uses `equals`, not `compareTo`.

Comment: @assylias: The point stands, but thanks for the correction :)

Comment: No I don't, should have mentioned that, and that I haven't overridden contains or equals.

Comment: The only way the loop in your first example can print false is if `anEpisode.equals(anEpisode)` returns false. Does `Episode` extend another class that has its `equals` method overriden?

Comment: No it doesn't extend another class.

Comment: Use a debugger and actually check what the contents of the collection is when it prints false!

Comment: Please write a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you create and post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that replicates the behavior?

Comment: I added what you said `this.episodes.contains(episode) + " equals " + episode.equals(episode)` prints "false equals true"

Comment: I'm not sure I can do an SSCCE that replicates the behavior, for one thing because a very similar class has different behavior and I can't see a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for(Episode episode : this.episodes) {
    System.out.println(string + this.episodes.contains(episode));
}
```

> Why would the above code print false?

In a generic sense, using a standard collection, the only way that I can see if if there are bugs in your `equals()` method.  With most collections, `contains()` iterates through the collection and uses `equals()`.  The `Object.equals()` would work so it could be that you have overridden the default `equals` method and there is a bug in it.

This is also what [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does.  If the collection is *eager* then it calls `contains()` on the inner `ArrayList` for the item which would use `equals()`.  If the collection is *lazy* then it uses the iterator across the table and, again, uses `equals()` to see if matches.

**Edit:**

Aha.  You state that you have not overridden the `equals()` method.

One important thing to remember (in terms of ORMLite) is that this is a *lazy* collection, there is no storage of the objects in memory.  When you are iterating across the lazy collection, you get an instance of your `Episode` object from the database.  Then, when you call `contains()`, it iterates *again* through the collection creating new `Episode` objects from the database.  It tries to compare the two objects but they will *never* be equal if you are using `Object.equals()` because there are *not* the same object reference.

You *must* to override the `equals()` method to get `contains()` to work for lazy collections.

Also, although your post is probably a simplification of your code, you might consider pulling the lazy collection into an array and then iterating across that.   You can't do a `contains()` on the array but if you needed to search the array, you wouldn't be iterating twice through the database.

**Edit:**

So the solution turned out to be more complicated.  Turns out that the OP had a `Show`  object, with an eager collection of `Season` objects, each with another eager collection of `Episode` objects.   By default, whenever ORMLite has nested eager collections the inner one is turned into a *lazy* collection for performance reasons.  This is not well documented in version 4.40 unfortunately.  You can change this by setting the `maxEagerLevel = 2` (or more) on the `Show` object's collection.  See the [documentation on `maxEagerLevel`](http://ormlite.com/docs/max-eager).

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, maxEagerLevel = 2)
ForeignCollection<Season> seasons;
```

Comment: I haven't overridden contains or equals

Comment: @Eruza - Not `List.contains` -- `Episode.equals`.

Comment: I have @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true) so it shouldn't be that right?

Comment: Also the code you posted at your last edit still prints false.

Comment: Typo in my last edit @Eruza.  Fixed.  I can't see how that would happen with an eager collection.  I'm trying to reproduce it now but can't.  What version of ORMLite are you on?

Comment: Sigh.  Yeah right.  I've edited my answer.  Are you sure you have an eager collection?

Comment: I'm on version 4.40. I have a show object that contains seasons, each season contains episodes. Everything is the same that I can see between the 3, same database annotations, but this does NOT happen with seasons.contains(season) but it does with episodes.contains(episode).

Comment: Yes, I'm positive it's eager.`@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
 private Collection<Episode> episodes = new ArrayList<Episode>();`

Comment: AHA!  Ok.  That's a bit of information that I did not have before.  So even though it is marked as eager, it is being created as lazy.  This is a performance issue.  When you get a show, it does another database request to get the seasons.  Since the eager fetching can go on forever, by default any eager collections inside of the seasons are forced to be lazy.  If you want to change this you can increase `maxEagerLevel` on the show to be 2 or more.  See: http://ormlite.com/docs/max-eager

Comment: Sorry about this @Eruza.  This should be better documented.  I'll add a note in the docs in a couple of places about this.

Comment: Yep, that definitely fixed it, marked as answered.  Thank you very much for the help.  One last question, eclipse is flagging maxEagerForeignCollectionLevel as deprecated? Edit: I see, use maxEagerLevel, but it worked when added to the season not the show.

Comment: Unfortunately @Eruza the docs are behind the code.  I've fixed it in trunk.  The javadocs for that method should tell you to use `maxEagerLevel` instead.

Comment: This just caught me out again.  I think it's the cause of this issue that I wrote a couple of years ago:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ormlite-user/ZYvoV86bIcU

Comment: For the moment I'm putting a check in all my removes where by if the collection isEager() ==false then perform a delete using the Dao .I think this is a bug

Answer (score 0):

Now, ormlite, the object relational mapper, manages object, and their modification state. It provides also means to save a modified Episode; one of your mentioned points. But concerning the error: you should **create an equals**, based on value. In ORM and similar managed libraries you serialization might give you different instances of/proxies for the same object, and access to methods may be intercepted by byte code manipulation (AOP).

An example of [modification](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#SEC30):

```
for (Order order : account.orders()) {
    // if we are changing some field in the order
    order.setAmount(123);
    // then we need to update it in the database
    account.orders.update(order);
}
```